# Where is the AutoCompleteCustomSource Property collection data stored within VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, collections, autocomplete

So in Visual studio using a windows form project under a textbox, is a property under Misc called AutoCompleteCustomSource(Collection)

In this box, theres a little button (...) that you can use to add data with a "String Collection Editor"

This Editor is ok but im looking to add well over 700 lines into it. Where is the source of this data so I can just dump a load in? Can I just import a csv file somewhere?

Iv already tried doing it myself in the code but its visual Basic so its missing some stuff. [Following the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_AutoCompleteMode) doesnt work for me since I cant get "AutoCompleteCustomSource" to work in the code:

[image]

I just wanna add a ALOT of data into this

Comment: Yes, you can of course load the data from a text file or anything else, at run-time. When you have non-working code, you need to post that code, so the problem can be identified. The (simplified) code you found in that link is perfectly working.

Comment: @Jimi Sadly that code doesnt work because im using Visual Basic and NOT C#.

Where do I eneter this text file at run-time?

Comment: You probably haven't noticed, but in the upper-band there's a menu where you can choose the language. The sample code will change, based on that selection. VB.Net is of course on the list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea I could change the documentations language to suit my terrible choice of programming language! Big love to you Jimi